# Read and loop through S3 folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using a mapper and reducer python scripts and in my reducer i want to read a directory on an S3 bucket loop through that folder and gather all data in the text files and put them in a list.

After that i will compare the strings coming in from stdin with the ones i have in that list.

Here is what i have done, while it works locally it does not work on amazon EMR

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, re
# from pprint import pprint
# from glob import glob
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

dictionary = {}
parts_list = []
# MERGEDISTANCE  = 100
MERGEDISTANCE = int(sys.argv[1])
# index_file =  open('index.txt', 'r')

f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/source123")

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall('{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Contents'):
    for key in child.findall("{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}Key"):
        if key.text.startswith("output/part-"):
            key = key.text.replace("output/", "")
            parts_list.append(key)

def buildindex():
    j = 0
    while j < len(parts_list):
        f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/source123/output/" + parts_list[j])
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip()
            yield line
        j += 1
        f.close()


for suspicious_line in sys.stdin:
 .....
```

syslog

```
2016-05-12 18:04:37,323 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem (main): Consistency disabled, using com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as filesystem implementation
2016-05-12 18:04:37,559 INFO amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver (main): MetricsConfigRecord disabledInCluster: false instanceEngineCycleSec: 60 clusterEngineCycleSec: 60 disableClusterEngine: true maxMemoryMb: 3072 maxInstanceCount: 500 lastModified: 1463075998666 
2016-05-12 18:04:37,559 INFO amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver (main): Created MetricsSaver j-1CJMJ1D4HZ0N7:i-236379fb:RunJar:10872 period:60 /mnt/var/em/raw/i-236379fb_20160512_RunJar_10872_raw.bin
2016-05-12 18:04:39,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-47-61.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.47.61:8032
2016-05-12 18:04:39,703 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-47-61.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.47.61:8032
2016-05-12 18:04:40,199 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): Opening 's3://source123/mapper.py' for reading
2016-05-12 18:04:40,335 INFO amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver (main): Thread 1 created MetricsLockFreeSaver 1
2016-05-12 18:04:40,522 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): Opening 's3://source123/suspicious_reducer.py' for reading
2016-05-12 18:04:40,727 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader (main): Loaded native gpl library
2016-05-12 18:04:40,729 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec (main): Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 426d94a07125cf9447bb0c2b336cf10b4c254375]
2016-05-12 18:04:41,440 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): listStatus s3://source123/suspicious-input with recursive false
2016-05-12 18:04:41,652 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat (main): Total input paths to process : 21
2016-05-12 18:04:41,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): number of splits:83
2016-05-12 18:04:41,994 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): Submitting tokens for job: job_1463075989014_0001
2016-05-12 18:04:42,295 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl (main): Submitted application application_1463075989014_0001
2016-05-12 18:04:42,398 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): The url to track the job: http://ip-172-31-47-61.us-west-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1463075989014_0001/
2016-05-12 18:04:42,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Running job: job_1463075989014_0001
2016-05-12 18:04:50,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1463075989014_0001 running in uber mode : false
2016-05-12 18:04:50,508 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:09,683 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 1% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:12,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 2% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:13,728 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 4% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:15,746 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 5% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:16,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 11% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:17,769 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 20% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:18,777 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 30% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:19,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 36% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:20,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 40% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:21,796 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 46% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:22,804 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 55% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:23,826 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 76% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:24,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 83% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:25,842 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 84% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:27,854 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 86% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:30,872 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 87% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:31,878 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 89% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:32,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 92% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:33,891 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 96% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:35,903 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 99% reduce 4%
2016-05-12 18:05:36,908 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 99% reduce 5%
2016-05-12 18:05:37,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 9%
2016-05-12 18:05:37,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000008_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,954 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000021_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000025_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,963 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000019_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,964 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000022_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,966 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,967 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000007_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,969 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000014_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000015_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:37,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000016_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:38,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 7%
2016-05-12 18:05:38,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000011_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:38,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000005_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:38,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000020_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:38,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000017_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:38,991 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000024_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:38,992 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000003_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:39,003 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000012_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:39,004 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000010_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:39,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000018_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:39,008 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000009_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,024 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:05:40,028 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000028_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,032 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000023_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,034 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000004_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,040 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000002_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,043 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000026_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:40,046 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000013_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:41,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000029_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:42,063 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000027_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:42,070 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000030_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:44,083 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000031_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:44,084 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000032_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:45,091 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000033_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:47,104 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000034_0, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:51,128 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000005_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:51,130 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000020_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:51,131 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000010_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:51,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000011_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:51,134 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000017_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:51,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000003_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:52,142 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000012_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:52,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000016_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:52,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000024_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,154 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000021_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,156 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000025_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,158 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000022_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,159 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000019_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000007_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,162 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000009_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,163 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000015_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000014_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000001_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:53,167 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000006_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,184 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000002_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000023_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000008_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,199 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000004_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000013_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,203 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000026_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000028_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:54,213 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000029_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:55,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000030_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:55,224 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000018_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:55,225 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000027_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:55,226 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000032_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:57,237 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000033_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:57,239 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000031_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:05:58,245 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000034_1, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:03,271 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000003_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:03,272 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000020_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:04,279 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000015_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:04,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000005_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,287 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000010_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,288 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000011_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,289 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000017_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,290 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000018_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,292 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000009_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000016_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000012_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:05,295 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000001_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:06,302 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000007_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:06,303 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000006_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:06,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000024_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:06,306 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000026_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:06,307 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000014_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:07,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000022_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:07,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000028_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:07,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000019_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:07,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000025_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,325 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 3%
2016-05-12 18:06:08,329 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000021_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000032_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,332 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000013_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,333 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000029_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000002_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,336 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,337 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000027_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,338 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000004_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,340 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000030_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:08,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000008_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:09,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 0%
2016-05-12 18:06:09,348 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000023_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:09,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000034_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:09,351 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000031_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:10,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1463075989014_0001_r_000033_2, Status : FAILED
2016-05-12 18:06:16,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 100%
2016-05-12 18:06:16,400 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1463075989014_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1463075989014_0001_r_000020
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1

2016-05-12 18:06:16,531 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Counters: 44
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=12207382
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=9296
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=83
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        S3: Number of bytes read=2432462
        S3: Number of bytes written=0
        S3: Number of read operations=0
        S3: Number of large read operations=0
        S3: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed reduce tasks=106
        Killed map tasks=1
        Killed reduce tasks=34
        Launched map tasks=83
        Launched reduce tasks=140
        Data-local map tasks=83
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=81896490
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=133401060
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1819922
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=1482234
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1819922
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=1482234
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=2620687680
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4268833920
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=33221
        Map output records=62063
        Map output bytes=5121017
        Map output materialized bytes=1515128
        Input split bytes=9296
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=62063
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=21830
        CPU time spent (ms)=104080
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=40538492928
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=170405302272
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=46246920192
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=2432462
2016-05-12 18:06:16,531 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob (main): Job not successful!
```

part of stderr log

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

any clues welcomed

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's the exact error message? If it works in one environment but not another then the code is probably fine and you are just missing some environment configuration.

Comment: @MarkB i know right, but for some reason it does not and i do not get an exact error, i pasted the syslog for reference.